# Azure Functions metric to show number of concurrent hosts running

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a metric that I can look at to see the number of hosts running concurrently in Azure Functions?  The functions are running in the Consumption plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have integrated Application Insights with Azure Functions, then you can see the number of (serverless) instances in the Live Metrics of Application Insights. Below is an example where you see two (serverless) instances - 1st and 3rd the ones that you see in the below image.

[image]

Integrate Azure Functions with App Insights, try to create some load and then go to Application Insights's Live Metric blade where you can view the servers running for your Azure Functions.

Update:

You can also view the instances in the "Diagnose & Solve Problems --> Availability & Performance --> Overview section..